# gettext() in selenium - can't find the function

Tags: c#, selenium

I am new in Selenium.
I want to print something and I saw that Selenium uses the command and function `gettext()` to print something.

When I tried to do this:

```
string address = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div.page-container > div.page-content-wrapper > div > div.portlet.box.grey-cascade > div.portlet-body > div.row.note.note-info > div.col-md-6 > address").<---
```

And put `.gettext()`, Selenium doesn't recognize the function. 
What did I do wrong? Maybe there's something I need to add?

Answer (score 1):

`IWebElement` in `C#` doesn't have `gettext()` method, it has `Text` member

```
string address = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > div.page-container > div.page-content-wrapper > div > div.portlet.box.grey-cascade > div.portlet-body > div.row.note.note-info > div.col-md-6 > address")).Text;
```

Comment: @מירוןברנד `Console.WriteLine(address);`

Comment: In What window I see the print ?

Comment: @מירוןברנד In the output window. Have a look at this link to learn how to use it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hk6fby3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one closing bracket in your code `)`. Try following:

```
String address = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > div.page-container > div.page-content-wrapper > div > div.portlet.box.grey-cascade > div.portlet-body > div.row.note.note-info > div.col-md-6 > address")).getText();
```

Let me know, if it is still not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Try This way

```
String address = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > div.page-container > div.page-content-wrapper > div > div.portlet.box.grey-cascade > div.portlet-body > div.row.note.note-info > div.col-md-6 > address")).getText();
System.out.println(address);
```

If this will not work then please share the HTML elements so that I can look into it.

Comment: The OP uses C#, not Java.